# Metal detector vs ground penetrating radar (GPR) frequencies

Tags: magnetics, detector, metal, gprs

I was reading about metal detectors and at first got thinking they use lower frequencies because of ground/rock losses. Low frequencies will penetrate better, but seeing GPRs penetrating much deeper and using much higher frequencies got me wondering why most metal detectors use 5-20 kHz while GPRs use 100-1000 MHz.

Searching on the web most answers saying its because "those low frequencies are better to find gold metals" - but it doesn't make sense because as far as I understand it, going to high frequencies will have better chance to be close to the resonance of the "treasure" and induce more eddy currents?

What is the real reason?

Answer (score 7):

> *So what is the real reason ?*

Low frequencies with moderate sized coils means low/moderate inductive reactance and, when parallel tuned with a capacitor, large circulating currents can be made to flow (amps) without the expense of that current being sourced from the battery.

- A much higher frequency means a much smaller current flow for a given applied voltage.
- High current means high magnetic field; low current means low magnetic field.
- More magnetic field means deeper penetration.

However, higher frequency means higher rate of change of flux and this can certainly counter the problems mentioned earlier.

However, the main reason why detectorists prefer low frequencies is that the unwanted effects of a wet-ground signal are much reduced. These are electric field effects between transmit and receive coil and are unrelated to the magnetic fields produced but, are significantly more problematic at higher frequencies.

GPR generates a pulse EM wave and, EM waves reduce in amplitude with \$\text{distance}^2\$. Magnetic fields (that don't form part of an EM wave) reduce in amplitude with \$\text{distance}^3\$ (beyond a certain point) and so are less able to penetrate deeply compared to a pulsed RF.

GPR emits a thin TX pulse that turns-off before the RF reflection returns. A regular metal detector has to both transmit a signal and look for the tiny return signal coming back and, be able to detect it in the presence of the continuous transmit signal (much trickier in terms of signal to noise) but, it gives you the opportunity of being able to discriminate between ferrous and non-ferrous signals (important for detectorists).

GPR will detect rocks as well as metal objects. GPR will also detect strata layer changes. Do you really want those "features" when looking for Saxon buried treasure in Staffordshire fields or would you prefer to discriminate against these unwanted things in favour of metals?

Comment: "A much higher frequency means a much smaller current flow for a given applied voltage" that is true only for that same coil - not for properly designed antenna , im not suggesting using same basic design of metal detector and rise the frequency

Comment: Of course for the same coil. For a smaller coil it can have a higher frequency for the same current. However, a smaller coil (due to its reduced area), will not penetrate as deep as a larger coil; the point where the magnetic field strength becomes an inverse cube law is much closer to the coil when it is smaller. I only have the details in your question to "work with" when making an answer @RonVaisman

Comment: The question is for generaly frequencies with ideal iradiators

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to imply @RonVaisman

Comment: As far as i can understand your answer - the metal detectors use low frequencies *only* because most designs use coils (or some type of magnetic loop antenna)?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking me a question or confirming what I said. Please make it easier for me to help you by asking a more direct question.

Comment: My question is : what are the properties that of low frequency magnitic field that benefit metal detection - that EM field at higher frequencies dont have? (Independent of the specific design of antenna used today)

Comment: Discrimination is the property. The ability to recognize good signals from false signals.

Comment: @RonVaisman are we done with this question and answer now or are you still waiting for other answers to might answer didn't cover?